# (Android)(Facebook) Multiple ProfilePictureViews cause OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, facebook, out-of-memory

I'm writing an app that integrates with Facebook.
My app has an option to show a friends' list.

Each item in the list has a `ProfilePictureView`:

```
<com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:id="@+id/fli_profilePicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:is_cropped="true"
    app:preset_size="small" />
```

And then the list adapter sets the users' ids into each item's `ProfilePictureView` :

```
    ProfilePictureView profilePicture = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.fli_profilePicture);        
    profilePicture.setProfileId(friendsList.get(position).getId());
```

**But this way, if you scroll too much, the `ListView` throws an OutOfMemoryError**.

Is it because the `ProfilePictureView` downloads large versions of the profile pictures, and then only scales them to small? If so, how do I set it to just download the pictures in small sizes?

Or is there another way to combat this?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should recycle your image too.

Comment: Hi LoneDuck, iam also facing the same issue..can u help me if you solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably reduce memory consumption by scaling down downloaded images

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

here a nice tutorial to download images in ListView
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/

Hope that helps you :)